# Wordpress "Posts Page" isn't showing template dropdown

Tags: posts, pages, templates

I am trying to add a custom tempalate to my "Posts Page"(archive, shows all blog posts) in wordpress, but there doesn't seem to be a template dropdown available. On any other page, It has a template dropdown and is showing that the template that im wanting to use is available. Any idea why this is? Is their limitations on adding a template to the "Posts Page"?

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

Welcome to StackExchange!

Page Templates are only able to be defined in the Page post type ("Pages" in the WP-admin).

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#uses-for-page-templates

You can edit your theme (or create a child theme) to define how your post pages are displayed. Depending on your needs you could define an archive.php, category.php or index.php in your theme and then write the PHP/HTML necessary to display your posts the way you'd like. You can find more information on that here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy

Hope this help.